# How to get Roo integration tests to work with AnnotationConfigContextLoader

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo

I have been running roo generated integration tests for quite a while with XML-based spring configuration and spring 3.1.  However, I have recently changed from XML-based configuration to java based configuation and also upgraded from Spring 3.1 to Spring 4.0.

Unfortunately, my roo genenerated integration tests now fail with the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Test class [com.bulb.learn.domain.CounterIntegrationTest] has been configured with @ContextConfiguration's 'locations' (or 'value') attribute {classpath*:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml}, but AnnotationConfigContextLoader does not support resource locations.
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader.validateMergedContextConfiguration(AnnotationConfigContextLoader.java:164)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 32 more
```

I know this is being caused by this line in the roo generated aspect file:

```
declare @type: CounterIntegrationTest: @ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath*:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml");
```

That is because I use this for my main test class base class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "junit")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { CoreConfig.class }, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public abstract class CoreIntegrationTest {
    ... 
}
```

Here is how I define the class that is annotated by @RooIntegrationTest

```
@RooIntegrationTest(entity = Counter.class, transactional = false)
public class CounterIntegrationTest extends CoreIntegrationTest {
```

However, I am not sure how to fix it.

The roo tests used to run fine.  They also run fine with just upgrading to Spring 4.0.  They also run fine with just changing to java configuration for Spring 3.1.  However, they don't work with both (Spring 4.0 with Java config)

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get these to work without simply removing them from roo control and removing the offending line myself?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Roo looks at the annotated class to see if it already has a `@ContextConfiguration` before it adds one to the aspect.  Unfortunately, it doesn't check to see if it has inherited a `@ContextConfiguration`.

I was able to solve the issue by adding a default `@ContextConfiguration` to the annotated class like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RooIntegrationTest(entity = Counter.class, transactional = false)
public class CounterIntegrationTest extends CoreIntegrationTest {
```

This prevents Roo from generating its own, and therefore the error goes away.